# Jmeter Script for Opco

Tags: jmeter

We need to work on client location from my machine
how can I record scripts in jmeter from my machine to different location
and what type of configurations I can have to do that

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to take remote connection of your machine from your client location.

You can normally configure your browser's proxy.

1. Connect to your machine from client location
2. Configure your browser's proxy for recording the Jmeter script.

Look into this [step by step guide](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) to Setup browser's proxy.